# I applied for a France fellowship with my university as my host organisation. Now PhD supervisor is fighting with me and making grounds to give TC?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, india

I am pursuing PhD at a university in India under a toxic supervisor. I received a fellowship in France for which the university is given as host. I got the results that I am selected for the fellowship in July 2023. My supervisor gave me NOC for visa purposes. Now due to some personal issues, she harassed me and I applied for a change of guide, but the university is not supporting me. I found out that the professor brings too many central government funded projects to the university. And when I approached the dean with my issues, he made a statement that I am trying to hold on to my PhD just for the fellowship in France and not for other reasons.

My intention was to do a PhD with foreign exposure and build collaborations to get postdocs abroad.  If my university removes me from the PhD program, will my fellowship get cancelled or will they consider my situation? I am very scared as this is happening in the last moment.

Comment: This is probably too vague to collect any useful answers. Why do you think the university will remove you from their PhD program? Typically this requires more than a professor with a bad attitude.

Comment: What are "NOC" and "TC" please.

Comment: No Objection Certificate for visa and Transfer certificate